# Configuring watchify and browserify to re-run only the required files

Tags: javascript, performance, gulp, browserify

I started working on a chrome extension.
So far I setup the project using gulp to watch the folder containing the code for background, popup, content and a few other pages.
Each component shares some some code with the others.

The problem is that every time I edit a file  watchify will trigger a full rebuild.

I have tried to limit the browserify process to only handle the files that have changed. It works very well for root scripts (popup.js, background.js, content.js)...
But unfortunately I have no way of tracking dependencies (files required by the root scripts or their dependencies) and this strategy fails when a dependency is edited.

So here is my question is there a good strategy to automatically update any dependent script upon change while avoiding a full browserify of the entire tree?

```
gulp.task('babel', () => {
  buildingTasks.start('babel');
  return gulp.src(scriptSrc)
  .pipe(through2.obj(function (file, enc, next){
    var b = browserify(file.path, {
      debug: (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')
    });
    b.transform(babelify, {presets: ['es2015', 'react']});
    b.bundle(function(err, res){
      if (err) return next(err);
      file.contents = res;
      next(null, file);
    });
  }))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('map'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(scriptDest))
});
```

I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35772932/edit) to access the dependencies list, but it would require building a dependency tree by hand, storing it somewhere and updating it every time a build is triggered. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Browserify to watch the bundled files, you need to configure Watchify:

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
var watchify = require('watchify');

...

var options = Object.assign({}, watchify.args, {
  debug: (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')
});
var b = watchify(browserify(file.path, options));
```

The `watchify` methods wrap the Browserify bundler and provides some shared arguments via `options` that are used to determine which files need to be watched. It returns the same bundler that would have been returned by `browserify`.

Comment: finally I went this road and stoped using gulp.watch for browserify.